# mysql select to fetch rows grouped by columns in the same result row

Tags: mysql

Table1:

```
bookid type 
 1      A
 2      B
 3      A
```

Table 2

```
recordid bookid   

  1         1        
  1         2        
  1         3
```

Is there a way to get the output as

```
recordid count(A) count(B)
  1           2       1
```

I tried grouping by left joining the two tables but that gives the output like this:

```
recordid type count
 1          A   2
 1          B   1
```

Please suggest the optimal way to get the required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `SUM()` with expression,using sum with expression will result in a boolean 1 and 0 and you can get the count based on your conditions

```
SELECT 
t2.recordid,
SUM( t1.type='A')  `CountA`,
SUM( t1.type='B')  `CountB`,
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 USING(bookid)
GROUP BY t2.recordid
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT 
t2.recordid,
count(CASE WHEN t1.type='A' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as CountA,
count(CASE WHEN t1.type='B' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as CountB,
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.bookid=t2.bookid
GROUP BY t2.recordid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have limit column type value, I think very easy to do. But If you have so many column type value, seem have only one way is procedure with cursor to do.

Comment: yeah, it is limited..I only have A, B and C..Thanks